# not getting the value on string after returning from otheer controller

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a button in a custom cell which is connected to IBAction method -`downloading`. When i click on the button, then i get the index path of clicked cell and getting the value of array  into sting from that index path. HEre is my code

```
  -(IBAction)downloading:(id)sender
{
  if(abletodownload){
classvalue = 1;
UITableViewCell *clicked = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
clickedPath = [self.tableview indexPathForCell:clicked];        
 idstring =[arr7 objectAtIndex: clickedPath.row]; 
 NSLog(@"idstring.....%@",idstring);

 urlstring = [arr6 objectAtIndex: clickedPath.row];
 holdingurlstring =[[NSString alloc]initWithString:urlstring];
NSLog(@"urlstring...%@",holdingurlstring);

titlestring = [arr2 objectAtIndex: clickedPath.row];
holdingtitlestring = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:titlestring];
NSLog(@"titlestring.....%@",titlestring);

 objInAppClass = [[InAppClass alloc]init];
[objInAppClass canmakepayment];}
```

Then i allocate and initiate the InAppClass and did all functionality of InAppPurchase.
bur when i return from InAppClass then i could not get the value of `holdurlstring`and `holdtitlestring`in else part here is the code.

```
 else{

    abletodownload = TRUE;
    NSLog(@"holdurlstring...%@",holdurlstring);
    NSLog(@"holdtitlestring.....%@",holdtitlestring);   

    [self connectionwithrequest];   
}
}
```

In short i need to save the value of urlstring and titlstring after returning back from InAppClass . What to do?

Answer (score 0):

1. in custom cell class create an instance of the view controller wher u want the value and synthesize it. HomeViewControllerClassName  *containerView;
2. in the view controller when u callin the custom cell set its container property to self. 
   ((CustomCellClassName*)cell).containerView = self;

   create a method in ur view controller -(void) getDetailsFromCustomCell:(NSUrl *)urlString;
3. 4m whichever place u want the data to be sent call the viewController method

   [containerView getDetailsFromCustomCell:urlstring];

same way u can pass any no of values to the controller class.

all the best...

Comment: :i am not using any custom cell class. I created separate empty nib where i placed UITableViewCell with identifier and buttons inside it from library. Then i called that nib in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: secondly i just want the 'holdurlstring' and 'holdtitlestring' value in else part as they are in if part. In If part it showing the values before shifting control to inappclass. but later on its not.